# Invisibility of the one element go through the other(white) as well to Background image

Tags: html, css

this is my code:

```css
body{
   background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/29628/pexels-photo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover; 
}

.header{
   height:2em;
   width:100%;
   position:fixed;
   top:0; left:0;
   background-color:white;
}
.main{
   width:100%;height:10em;
   margin-top:5em;
   background-color:white;
}
.mainPanel{  
   width:50%;
   margin:auto;
   background-color:yellow;
   height:5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="mainPanel">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

I want that the yellow div is transparent and shows the background image of body. That the yellow div go trough the white div behind it and shows the background image of body. Is that possible? I hope it comes clear what i meant.

Comment: You want see the white background or the image ?

Comment: I want that the yellow div shows the background image of body

Comment: So you want the invisibility of the yellow element go through the white as well?

Comment: right, thats what i want

Comment: you can use svg `<mask>` or svg `<clipPath>`

Comment: Isnt this duplicate, @Paulie_D, he wants the yellow rectangle to be a window (like clipping/mask) on the white div, not just set it transparent.

Comment: @F.Dengler If someone's solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of would involve breaking your white box into three rectangles and arranging them to form a window of sorts. Here, try this out:

```css
body {
   background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/29628/pexels-photo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   background-size: cover; 
}

.header {height:2em;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0; left:0;}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
.mainPanel{  
    width:50%; 
    margin:auto;
    height:5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>

   <div id="left-rectangle" style="background-color: white; width: 25%;height: 160px; position: absolute;"></div>
   <div class="right-rectangle" style="background-color: white; width: 25%; float: right; height: 160px;"></div>
   <div class="center-rectangle" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 25%;background-color: white;width: 50%;height: 80px;margin-top: 80px;"></div>
   <div class="header">
   </div>
   <div class="main">
   </div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply repeat the background, and since it has a `fixed` position, it will be exactly like the `body` background and you will not notice a difference.

```
body, .mainPanel {
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/29628/pexels-photo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Simply extend the background of `body` to `.mainPanel` to create the illusion.

**Demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/wyndddgg/)**

```css
html, body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}

body, .mainPanel {
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/29628/pexels-photo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header {
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  background-color: white;
}

.mainPanel {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 5em;
  border:1px dashed #CCC; /* just for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="mainPanel">
  </div>
</div>
```